# In C programming and using malloc, where is the free() in a pointer function that returns a pointer?

Tags: c, malloc, function-pointers, free

I have created a pointer function that returns a pointer. I place a `malloc`inside the function but then, I don't know whether to put the `free()` and if so, if it has to go in the function or in `main`.

Comment: you free the allocated memory when you do not need it, It can be anywhere

Comment: Just make a note in the comments above the function that the *caller is responsible for freeing the return*.

Answer (score 0):

You free allocated memory when you don't need it see this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int *fun()
{
     int *ptr=malloc(sizeof(int));

     if(ptr==NULL)
     {
         printf("Error");
         exit(1);
     }

     return ptr;
}

int main()
{
     int*ptr=fun();

     /*do something*/

     /*After all work of ptr is done*/
     free(ptr);

     /*do something*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You typically call free when you are confident that you have finished using the allocated pointer.  It's also a good practice to indicate whether returned values should be free'd or not.  Here's one example of organizing a method in C:

```
int main() {
  //let's start our method with initializing any declarations
  int mystringlen = 25;
  char* mystring1 = NULL;
  char* mystring2 = NULL;

  //let's now assign some data
  mystring1 = malloc(mystringlen * sizeof(char));  
  if (mystring1 == NULL) goto end; //malloc failure :(
  strncpy(mystring1, "Hello world", mystringlen);

  //strdup(3) mallocs its return value, we should be careful and check
  //documentation for such occurances
  mystring2 = strdup("hello world");
  if (mystring2 == NULL) goto end; //malloc failure


  //let's do our processing next
  printf("%s\n%s\n", mystring1, mystring2);


  //let's do our cleanup now
  end:
    if (mystring1) free(mystring1);
    if (mystring2) free(mystring2);
    return 0;
}
```

There's a few conventions available and some may object to using goto for flow control.  Note that we set our pointers to `NULL` so that we can later do safe cleanup.  We're also checking for malloc failures which is a good practice.